# On the proof of Gelfand formula in $C^{\star}$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

I was reading the proof in Bratteli-Robinson's book on $C^{\star}$-algebra that
$$\rho(A)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\|A^n\|^{1/n}$$ for some element $A$ of a $C^{\star}$-algebra $\mathcal{U}$ (Prop 2.2.2 page 26).

At some point they set $$r_A=\limsup_{n\to \infty}\|A^n\|^{1/n}$$ and act by contradiction assuming that $\rho(A)<r_A$. At the end, they obtain that
\begin{equation}\label{eq}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\|A^n\|}{r_A^n}=0\end{equation}  and say this contradict the definition of $r_A$. I do not agree with that as it is easy to construct sequences $v_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}v_n^{1/n}=a$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{v_n}{a^n}=0$. What am I missing ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: I think you are right The book should take $r$ such that $\rho (A) <r <r_A$ and show that $\frac {\|A\|^{n}} {r^{n}} \to 0$.